# Swapping special keys

Tags: linux, emacs, xorg, xmodmap

I am on archlinux and trying to swap the left Alt key with the left Ctrl key for my convenience in emacs as well as bash command line editing. I use the following ~/.xmodmap:

```
remove mod1 = Alt_L
remove control = Control_L
keycode 37 = Alt_L
keycode 64 = Control_L
add mod1 = Control_L
add control = Alt_L
```

For some unclear reason to me, although xev output shows that indeed the two keys are swapped, no application actually uses the new bindings. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: I removed lines 3 and 4 and the problem is solved. All I needed to do is just remove the key from its original modifier and rebind it to the desired one. By swapping the keycodes I effectively rebound the each key to its original modifier. How silly of me!

Comment: @stk, you can mark this question answered, if you post the above comment as answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

You are switching it twice so it returns to the origin.

Instead you should have changed `modifier`:

```
remove mod1 = Alt_L
remove control = Control_L
add mod1 = Control_L
add control = Alt_L
```

or `keycode`:

```
remove mod1 = Alt_L
remove control = Control_L
keycode 37 = Alt_L
keycode 64 = Control_L
add mod1 = Alt_L
add control = Control_L
```

Check out [xmodmap(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmodmap) example, they `add` to the same modifier they `remove`d from:

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
remove Control = Control_L
keysym Control_L = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L
add Lock = Caps_Lock
add Control = Control_L
```